# tesseract OCR failed to recognize these numbers

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am having trouble getting these numbers recognized correctly. With "--psm 7", I got "lOON3S06", with "--psm 7 digits", I got "0306". The image is clear, resolution is good and there are enough white space around the text. Tried both version 4.1.1 and the latest 5 release. Any suggestions?

[image: number image]

Comment: did you try [dilating](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) the characters?

Comment: after a dilation with k=5, it worked. The problem however is that other text in the document would be touching each other after the dilation.